# sending email via netlify functions

Tags: javascript, forms, lambda, nodemailer, netlify

Im trying to write a lambda function to send a mail to a gmail adress, so i have a form in vuejs that post to this function:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const qs = require("querystring");

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {

  const {
    name,
    email,
    phone,
    message
  } = qs.parse(event.body);

  const sendMail = (name, email, phone, message) => {
      const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        user: "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
        pass: "xxxxxxx"
      }
    });
    const mailOptions = {
      from: email, // sender address
      to: "xxxxxxx@gmail.com", // list of receivers
      subject: `Message from ${name} to FoodAllergyFriendly website`, // Subject line
      html: `${name} avec l'adresse ${email} et le numéro de téléphone ${phone} a écrit ceci: <br> <p>${message}</p>` // plain text body
};
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log(info);
    });
  };
   sendMail();
   callback(null, {
     statusCode: 200,
      body: "Merci !"
   });
}
```

the message is well send but i have undefined for name, email, phone and message in my email. It seems i don't parse the body of my form in the right way. Anyone has a clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Your form POST from Vue.js so use JSON.parse(body) not qs which is used to parse query strings in URL